# How to simplify the following matrix problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Taken from the lecture notes: [Introduction to the principles and methods of data assimilation in the geosciences - Marc Bocquet](http://cerea.enpc.fr/HomePages/bocquet/teaching/assim-mb-en.pdf), where I am currently working on page 12.

> Given that:
> $$\mathrm{P^a=(I-KH)B+[KR-(I-KH)BH^T]K^T} \tag{1.27}$$
>
> the expression in brackets in the RHS is zero when $\mathrm{K=K^*}$
> resulting in $$\mathrm{P^a=(I-K^*H)B} \tag{1.26}$$ where
> $$\mathrm{K^*=BH^T(R+HBH^T)^{-1}}. \tag{1.23}$$

So we want to simplify Eq$(1.27)$ into Eq$(1.26)$ given Eq$(1.23)$.

---

Working with just the RHS terms within the brackets, we want to show $$\mathrm{[KR-(I-KH)BH^T]=0}.$$

Substitute for $\mathrm{K^*}$, $$\mathrm{[BH^T(R+HBH^T)^{-1}R-(I-BH^T(R+HBH^T)^{-1}H)BH^T]}$$

Then, factoring out $\mathrm{BH^T}$,

$$\mathrm{[(R+HBH^T)^{-1}R-I+(R+HBH^T)^{-1}HBH^T]}$$

From this point onward, how should I proceed? I considered using the Woodbury matrix identity, $$\mathrm{(R+HBH^T)^{-1} = R^{-1} - R^{-1}H (B^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1} H^TR^{-1}}.$$

However, that seems to end up in an "endless expansion":

$$\mathrm{[I- R^{-1}H (B^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1} H^T-I+R^{-1} - R^{-1}H (B^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1} H^TR^{-1}HBH^T]}$$

$$\mathrm{[R^{-1}H (B^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1} H^T+R^{-1} - R^{-1}H (B^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1} H^TR^{-1}HBH^T]}$$

Furthermore, if I have understood the lecture notes correctly, it doesn't imply the usage of the other form of $K^*$ obtained via the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury form as it indicated on the end of page 11, "Choosing the optimal gain Eq.(1.23)..."

Comment: You should quote the text from the book

Comment: @user675453 Is that what you meant?

Comment: ,I meant , quote the **text** so people can read more properly and distinguish what you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close.

From: $\mathrm{[(R+HBH^T)^{-1}R-I+(R+HBH^T)^{-1}HBH^T]}$

Note that $I = (R+HBH^T)^{-1} (R+HBH^T)$

So factor out: $(R+HBH^T)^{-1}$

$(R+HBH^T)^{-1}{[R-(R+HBH^T) +HBH^T]} = 0$

Comment: Now I'm just mad at myself for not thinking about using the identity matrix. Thanks!